# Eigen library function same as lapack dsyev_

Tags: eigen, lapack, eigenvalue

I downloaded some opensource using `lapack/blas` and i want to change that into `Eigen`based source for auto `SIMD` code generation.

Is there any function in `Eigen` library same as `dsyev` in `LAPACK`.

`dsyve` returns `info` value for several purposes.

but as far as i know, `eigensolver` in `Eigen` library returns  `eigenvalue` or `eigenvector`.

Is there a function what i want in `Eigen` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is [`.info()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html#a0c06d5c2034ebb329c54235369643ad2), as well as other APIs provided by [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html).

The [tutorial page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) also shows how to use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
   Matrix2f A;
   A << 1, 2, 2, 3;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix2f> eigensolver(A);
   if (eigensolver.info() != Success) abort();
   cout << "The eigenvalues of A are:\n" << eigensolver.eigenvalues() << endl;
   cout << "Here's a matrix whose columns are eigenvectors of A \n"
        << "corresponding to these eigenvalues:\n"
        << eigensolver.eigenvectors() << endl;
}
```

If you really want to know the details of `NoConvergence` as reported by [`dsyev()`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521120), you may have to use the low-level LAPACK API.

> This function returns a value info.
>
> If info=0, the execution is successful.
>
> If info = -i, the i-th parameter had an illegal value.
>
> If info = i, then the algorithm failed to converge; i indicates the
>   number of elements of an intermediate tridiagonal form which did not
>   converge to zero.

Comment: All i want to know is just success/fail(0 or not) i don't need reason of fail(-i~ +i) thank you for your answer.